# Flipflop's output voltages are 0V

Tags: flipflop, counter, pspice

I'm building a 4-bit asynchronous up counter with D flip-flops. Unfortunately the 4 output voltages are always 0V. Can someone please tell me why?

I had already placed a digital source in front of the first ‘D’ input, and that didn't help either.

I just saw that there is a *Power Pins visible* checkbox in the settings of every flip-flop. I checked the checkbox and saw a VCC pin appear. I connected a 5VDC source there. That didn't help either.

[image: circuit]

[image: simulation]

**Edit:** At \$U_3\$, no signal is coming in. Thus, I guess \$U_2\$ doesn't work.

[image: circuit, edit]

**Edit 2:** I separated the first flip-flop from the second. With the first one, I should also see the output voltage change.
Well, nothing happens. Regardless of whether it is a digital or pulse source. No matter which Youtube video I watch. All interconnect the flip-flop as shown in the picture. Nothing. Probably because of the program.

I'm using *PSpice for TI2020*

Comment: What tool are you using to build and simulate this circuit?

Comment: PSpice for TI2020

Comment: Are you initializing your flip flops before the clock starts running?  If not, then even though the FF's may be toggling, the simulator doesn't know how to display those outputs that are really unknown.

Comment: @SteveSh I have already changed "Edit Simulation Profile" → "Options" → "Gate Level Simulation" → "DIGINITSTATE" to 1. Did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solution of the problem for future readers**

That has now cost me 12 hours. I have to add that I'm a beginner and don't do it full-time. Apart from that – so much disinformation and at the same time problems in the program made the whole project difficult. Well, now I know how to do it.

Start a project and choose “Create based upon an existing project”; with “AnalogGNDSymbol.opj”. That was said in a forum post that I found while researching.

[image: create analog and digital project]

Now build the counter. To do this, select “DFFRH” for the flip-flops. I said in the question above that it should be enough to set the “DIGINITSTATE” to 0 or 1 in the settings—and you have to continue to do that—but according to another forum post I found, something is going wrong internally. Long story short: it just doesn't work. Therefore, please select the “DFFRH”. A pulse source is connected to the ‘reset’ inputs, which ‘fires’ once at the beginning to clear all undefined states. Imagine in practice a [button](https://www.led1.de/shop/images/thumbnail/produkte/medium/Produktbilder/Taster.jpg) that you press briefly once and which brings a voltage to the ‘reset’ inputs.

[image: circuit]

One more thing: By the way, it is like I show an *up* counter. I had first found a website according to which it is supposedly a *down* counter when you go from ‘Q’ to the ‘Clock’ of the next flip-flop. Unfortunately, that was wrong. What is pictured on the website is an *up* counter. That's a pity. I was so confused at times that I briefly thought [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts4g_NUuHAc) video was wrong – but it was the only right one. I mean, well, there could be other solutions – that probably depends on the flip-flop. Even in my old university documents—and fortunately I took a few screenshots with my smartphone at the time—it says that a forward counter \$\overline{Q}\$ has to be connected to the next ‘clock’ input.

Anyway, it looks good this way (it starts at 2.5 seconds).

[image: graphs]

Comment: "up" or "down"-ness doesn't come from the clock connection, it comes from the data connection.  Tap your resistors to the feedback from /Q instead of from Q and look at what happens.

Comment: Alternatively, keep the resistors connected to Q, and flip the diodes around, with 5V at the other terminal.